# Handling urls and routes with a state machine in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

Curious to know if there are any patterns around the following scenario. It looks like a state machine of some type is needed:

- Two collections (let's say Cars and Birds, just making this up)
- You can drill down into either collection and see a detail view
- Each collection has a view tied to it, there's also a detail view of each
- Want to prevent duplicating code in router.on methods and keep things dry (perhaps just one method then that looks at the state of cars and does something, and the same for birds?)

**state**: cars - birds
**url**: #

**state**: car detail - birds
*url*: #/cars/1

**state**: car detail - bird detail
**url**: #/cars/1/birds/1

**state**: cars - bird detail
**url**: #birds/1

Answer (score 1):

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    '*variables': 'drawViews'
},

parse: function(variables) {
    values = variables.split("/");
    return values;
},

drawViews: function(variables) {
    values = this.parse(variables);
//and here you check the first value and see it its car or bird then you get      
//next value of the array wich will be the index and so on. 
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice mini-tutorial on exactly this subject [here](http://marksoper.me/Backbone-Routing-Lessons-Learned-Subrouters-and-State-Machines.html). Also a [state machine mixin](https://github.com/sebpiq/backbone.statemachine) from the Backbone website, but doesn't seem to target routers in particular